# Rendering React SVG Components as images (using DATA URI)

Tags: reactjs, svg, optimization, server-side-rendering, data-uri

Hi to optimize my huge svg components I'm tryin to do something similiar to this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ians/rendering-svgs-as-images-directly-in-react-a26615c45770
, so far I've come up with this

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server'
function Image({children})  {
    let draw = <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">{children}</svg>
    let svgToMiniDataURI = require('mini-svg-data-uri')
    let image = svgToMiniDataURI(renderToStaticMarkup(draw))
   return <image href={image} />
}
export default Image
```

It's working pretty good but I don't want to use renderToStaticMarkup for one reason:
I use getBBox method inside my SVG components and that's something really hard to avoid using.

Any Idea on how I could achieve something similiar without using SSR? Or any way to get getBBox working on server side (I saw phantomjs but I think that would kill performance instead of helping and it doesn't seem like a really nice solution)

Comment: multiple ways, but without looking at SVG it would be difficult. 1. You can try minify the svg by running it through some svg minifier like https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ 2. Probably convert the svg to an avif or webp format image but would need to check the amount of KB it generates and is it really worth the try.

Comment: The svg goes through SVGO but it's not enough, the svg has like one symbol and a lot of use (is kind of like a pattern but it's never really repeating itself (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperiodicity#:~:text=Quasiperiodicity%20is%20the%20property%20of,lend%20itself%20to%20precise%20measurement) ) so the only way to make it more light for the browser is to let it treat it like an image instead of inline svg (this way all the nodes of the svg won't be treated as dom nodes (callBacks, events, and other slow html browser stuff)

Comment: From what I know, I think you have only one option and that is to directly use an Image instead of SVG. I would recommend to formats, `avif` and `webp`. Both have good compression and quality compared to JPEG and PNG. Check https://caniuse.com/avif and https://caniuse.com/webp for browser support though.

Comment: You can further optimise the image by reducing the quality (For me, when using `webp` and `avif` the quality between `60` and `80` usually suffice for web and mobile applications).

Comment: Thanks but I need to stick with SVG as these patterns are dinamically created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the alternative to do this would be to get a reference of the component we load in the page, get its html content after it has been rendered by React and then change it. Here's the code for my example
function Image({children})  {
let svgToMiniDataURI = require('mini-svg-data-uri')

```
  const imageContainer = React.useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      Image.timer = setTimeout(()=>{ //I used this delay so my component get its useEffects done
        const image = svgToMiniDataURI(node.outerHTML)
        //here we could have also set a state with the href value and then based on that state in the return we choose to render the image instead of the normal comp 
        if (node.parentNode)
          node.outerHTML = `<image href="${image}" />`
      }, 0.1)
    }
  }, []) 
React.useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(Image.timer);
  }
}, [])
return <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ref={imageContainer}>{children}</svg>
}
```